# Run jar on remote machine as background process over ssh

Tags: java, bash, ssh

I want to run a jar as a background process on a remote machine over ssh connection. There is bash script on remote machine to execute jar

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/location/of/java/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
nohup java -jar jar_name.jar config.properties &
```

If I execute the above script directly from remote machine(`sudo ./start_script.sh`), jar is started as background process and stdout is directed to `nohup.out` in the same folder as jar. But when I run script from local machine : `ssh vm_name 'sudo ./start_script.sh'`, the process starts up. but it blocks and the output is directed to local terminal.

is there way to achieve this?

EDIT: I need to run script as root and also pass parameters to script, added placeholder path for JAVA_HOME to avoid confusion

Comment: why using the sudo? Why explicitly setting JAVA_HOME empty then using it in PATH?

Comment: @Paul jar needs to access other resources which require super user privileges.

Comment: It it asking for a password?

Comment: I am giving proper location for JAVA_HOME, I just omitted that detail in the question because I thought that is irrelevant. Also No it does not ask for password.

Comment: try adding a `-t` option: `ssh vm_name -t 'sudo ./start_script.sh'`

Comment: that works, This is exactly I was looking for.  Thanks

Comment: Will add it as a solution. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the [`ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) to connect as a *terminal*.

```
ssh vm_name -t 'sudo ./start_script.sh'
```

It's likely recognizing that you are not on as a terminal and altering behavior accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue related here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/955268/what-is-the-difference-between-running-a-command-in-ssh-shell-manually-vs-runnin

Try

```
$ ssh user@host bash -l ./build.sh
```

Comment: Doesn't work. output is still directed to local terminal. Also another problem is process runs as user without root privileges